# How to fill pixel art circle area?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I would like to know how can I fill and color area which is in circle border area and how to remove area which is outside of circle border area and keep perfect shape? In general I have a pixel art image in circle shape and I need it to be perfectly shaped circle. Can you help me how to achiev that?

[image]

Comment: If it's a raster image you are working on, Illustrator is the incorrect tool to use.

Comment: Photoshop has a Pixel Perfect tool. Maybe that'll be of some use.

Comment: Is it possible to just add your own circle?

Comment: If you are making pure pixel art every pixel must align to the same grid, so it's not possible to have round shapes. But you can make a mix of pixel art and vector if you like. Is that what you want to achieve? What is it for?

Comment: A perfect circle in pixel art has its edge as one pixel wide stairs? Is that also your "perfect circle"? Or do you expect something which is at the same time a smooth continuous circular arc and a jagged staircase, not only one of these. I have seen a video where a person was hypnotized to see it possible(no idea was it fake or not). You can reduce bad jokes by drawing a sketch which shows what result is wanted and in what media. Your current image tells nothing about what's right and what's wrong.